Windows 10 disk not found when trying to boot from Grub
I just installed Bliss OS 16 on my laptop. I can boot to Bliss OS just fine but when I tried booting to Windows it gave the me
Error: disk 'hdWindows' not found

instead.
During GRUB2 installation a prompt to add sda1 that might contain Windows boot file to boot menu appeared and I selected yes.
I'm using legacy BIOS MBR, sda1 should be my Windows reserved partition and sda2 should be the Windows location. Bliss OS is located on sda4.
What should I do to be able to boot to windows?

Windows in old BIOS boot mode has boot partition that must have boot flag and not have grub installed into its partition boot sector. With BIOS/MBR, only one boot loader can be in the drive's MBR and that needs to be grub as Windows will not boot Ubuntu. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

@oldfred here's the BootInfo summary http://sprunge.us/vDE8iX
What to do next?

Looks like UEFI system, but old BIOS installs. With multiple drives best to keep each system on different drive and then have its own boot loader in that drive. Or grub in Linux install's drive & Windows boot loader in Windows drive. Then when selecting from UEFI/BIOS you can boot either system. Grub only boots working Windows. It looks like PBR/BS of sdc1 is damaged. You want to get to this screen for PBR or BS recovery:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

@oldfred sorry for not being specific earlier, but sdc is my live usb and most likely not related to the issue. For now I would like to boot back to windows without reinstalling if possible as that might give me the option to use grub2win instead.

I would still prefer separate boot loaders. Grub can be in sdb's MBR, even though install is in sda. And then Windows can be in sda's MBR. I believe Boot-Repair in BIOS mode, can put a Windows type (syslinux) boot loader into MBR of sda & reinstall grub to sdb. Use Boot-Repair's advance mode to choose install & drive. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Make sure boot flag is on sda1 as that is where Windows boot files are. Or after installing grub to sdb's MBR, use Windows repair/recovery drive to install Windows boot loader to sda.

I would first start by booting from an USB (Linux distro for example or from a windows recovery partition) to verify that the partitions you say actually contain the windows boot files.
The purpose of this preliminary check is to test whether the windows partitions are intact or overwritten by mistake.
In the latter case Windows OS  should be reinstalled.

Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that in its current form your post looks like troubleshooting advice rather than a definitive answer. If that was not intended, please edit the post to make the explanation clearer. Otherwise, it might be best placed as a comment under the original question.

I've verified that the windows partition is still intact and haven't been overwritten. I kinda suspect that grub set the booth path for windows incorrectly.
